# In a VMware environment, is it possible to move a Windows Disk from one VM guest to another?

Tags: vmware-esxi, windows-server-2012

I have VMware server with Windows SBS server VM guest.  It has a C: drive and a D: drive. The D: drive is a separate disk in the VM guest settings.

We would like to migrate this to a new Windows 2012 File Server.  I wonder if it is possible to create a new Windows server with a 60GB system disk (C: drive), and then do the following:

1) Shut down the SBS server VM guest.

2) Move the file or files associated with the second disk from the SBS VM folder on the esx host to the folder for the new Windows File server on the ESXi host, and then add that drive to the settings/configuration of the new file server guest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can attach the VMDK to another virtual machine.

Comment: Since I would be coming from SBS 2011 parition to a Windows Server 2012 R2 partition would it work?  I know that it would be NTFS, but would there be any issues or conflicts?

Comment: Yes, it will work.

Comment: I use this feature as a floating_drive to copy files from one VM on my network, to another VM connected to a VPN which doesn't allow USB or local network access after its connected. The only requirement is that your OS supports "hot add" for the Drive. You can even mount the primary disk from the old server if you change its Volume names.